# Laravel 8 Jetstream: unable to login with the account seeded using factories and seeder

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-jetstream, laravel-factory

I am working on a Laravel 8 project. I have noticed that a couple of things have changed including authentication. I am using Jetstream for authentication.

I have installed the Jetstream and I can register and login going to the route /register and /login on the browser. What I am doing now is that for local development, I am creating seeder class so that I can seed the users and log in using those seeded users for local development. But when I log in using those account, it is always complaining that "These credentials do not match our records.".

This is what I have done. I have registered an account on browser using password, "Testing1234". The password hash is saved in the users table. I copied the password and use it in the UserFactory class as follow.

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    use WithFaker;
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = User::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$tive4vPDzIq02SVERWxkYOAeXeaToAv57KQeF1kXXU7nogh60fYO2', //Testing.1234
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
}
```

Then I created a user using factory as follow.

```
User::factory()->create(['email' => 'testing@gmail.com']);
```

Then I tried to log in using the user I just created. But it is always complaining, "These credentials do not match our records.". I cannot use the other passwords too. Even the default password that comes with the default user factory class. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the issue.

In the JetstreamServiceProvider class, I have added the following code to customise the login flow.

```
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
            
        });
```

My bad. That is what makes it failing.

Comment: hi man, where exactly did you put that code ? can you show me? i have the exact problem now.

Comment: Me too, Jetstream insist personal team should be exist :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
User::factory()->make([
'email' => 'testing@gmail.com',
 ]);
```